# Should I grant sudo to a user or add CAP_SYS_ADMIN capabilities to use nvprof/ncu? And why?

Tags: pam, capabilities, setcap, cuda

Since CUDA 10.1, users are required to have sudo privileges to collect advanced metrics with cuda profiling tools such as `nvprof` or nsight compute (`ncu`).

Alternatives to get around it are described here:

- https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-err-nvgpuctrperm-nvprof

The link above mentions that CAP_SYS_ADMIN can be used in order to enable the collection of these metrics.

Trying to understand the problem, I found this insightful stack overflow response:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685265

Correct me If I am wrong, but in order to proceed with CAP_SYS_ADMIN path I should enable the capability for the application **AND** the user (if it is a non-root user).

I am not familiar with linux capabilities and I am not sure if is best to grant CAP_SYS_ADMIN to user/application or just give the user SUDO access. Why one is better than the other?

---

EDIT: As of right now, I am still unable to get it to work.

```
# First I executed
$ sudo setcap cap_sys_admin+ep /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvprof
```

```
# This is the command that I am executing after installing the CUDA toolkit 10.2.
$ /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvprof -o output-detailed.nvvp -f --analysis-metrics /usr/local/cuda/extras/demo_suite/vectorAdd

[Vector addition of 50000 elements]
==142443== NVPROF is profiling process 142443, command: /usr/local/cuda/extras/demo_suite/vectorAdd
Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device
CUDA kernel launch with 196 blocks of 256 threads
==142443== Some kernel(s) will be replayed on device 0 in order to collect all events/metrics.
==142443== Warning: ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM - The user does not have permission to profile on the target device. See the following link for instructions to enable permissions and get more information: https://developer.nvidia.com/ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM
Failed to launch vectorAdd kernel (error code unknown error)!
==142443== Warning: ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM - The user does not have permission to profile on the target device. See the following link for instructions to enable permissions and get more information: https://developer.nvidia.com/ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM
==142443== Warning: Some profiling data are not recorded. Make sure cudaProfilerStop() or cuProfilerStop() is called before application exit to flush profile data.
==142443== Generated result file: /results/nvprof/output-detailed.nvvp
```

But it only works if I run with sudo.

```
$ sudo /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvprof -o output-detailed.nvvp -f --analysis-metrics /usr/local/cuda/extras/demo_suite/vectorAdd

[Vector addition of 50000 elements]
==142687== NVPROF is profiling process 142687, command: /usr/local/cuda/extras/demo_suite/vectorAdd
Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device
CUDA kernel launch with 196 blocks of 256 threads
==142687== Some kernel(s) will be replayed on device 0 in order to collect all events/metrics.
Replaying kernel "vectorAdd(float const *, float const *, float*, int)" (done)
Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory
Test PASSED
Done
==142687== Generated result file: /home/agostini/Development/nvprof/output-detailed.nvvp
```

Why it is not enough to grant the capabilities to the executable and have super user to run the application without sudo. Is PAM setup really needed even for a user in the sudo group?

Comment: The Principle of Least Privilege suggests that granting root should always be the option of last resort. Any working alternative is superior.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` works, but it's probably much easier to just follow [the instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-err_nvgpuctrperm-permission-issue-performance-counters) that make it so a non root user can use the profiler.

```bsh
echo 'options nvidia "NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers=0"' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u 
sudo reboot
```